# Is dimensional modeling feasible with Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

As we know, the referential constraints are not enforced by Redshift. Should we still opt for dimensional modeling ?

If so, how do we get around the limitations and maintain data integrity of our datawarehouse.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, dimensional modelling is feasible and strongly encouraged on Redshift. Redshift is even optimized for star schema queries
[Optimizing for Star Schemas and Interleaved Sorting on Amazon Redshift](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx1WZP38ERPGK5K/Optimizing-for-Star-Schemas-and-Interleaved-Sorting-on-Amazon-Redshift)

Refer this [Is dimensional modeling feasible in Amazon RedShift?](https://www.quora.com/Is-dimensional-modeling-feasible-in-Amazon-RedShift)

Comment: But then, how do I maintain referential integrity in case of Star schema design ?

Comment: Why would referential integrity go bad?

Comment: @Sarang - I have recently answered this question on Quora - https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-maintain-the-referential-integrity-in-case-of-star-schema-in-Redshift

Comment: @tobi6 - Since uniqueness, primary key, and foreign key constraints are not enforced by Amazon Redshift